# maven plugin: parameter as field in object does not work properly

Tags: maven, plugins, parameter-passing

I have written a plugin for maven, https://github.com/Reissner/latex-maven-plugin.
It uses one parameter in the `InjectionMojo`

```
  @Parameter(name = "injections", defaultValue = "latexmkrc,chktexrc",
      property = "latex.injections")
  private Set<Injection> injections;`
```

which works just fine.
I can use the default and also he property from the command line.
The command line setting overwrites all.

Then I have another parameter which is part of the `CfgLatexMojo`:

```
  @Parameter(name = "settings")
  protected Settings settings;
```

The class `Settings` itself has a parameter

```
@Parameter(name = "targets", defaultValue = "chk,pdf,html", property = "latex.targets")//
  //private SortedSet<Target> targets;
  private String targets = "chk,pdf,html";
```

And here I observe strange things:
If I don't initialize `targets = "chk,pdf,html"` i get a `NullPointerException`,
although `defaultValue = "chk,pdf,html"` should be sufficient.

Also the property does not work.. Or maybe I don't know how to invoke properly.

There are further strange effects, but let us concentrate on these first.

Comment: To start, did you include a public setter  `public setTargets(String)`?

Comment: yes i do =: 
public void setTargets(String targets) {
    this.targets = targets.trim();
  }

Comment: Thought this was an interesting question.  After experimenting a bit, I'm not sure this is possible.  It looks to me like the 'property' attr of the @Parameter annotation may only be honored when the parameter is injected into a Mojo, but NOT when it is injected into another Java config bean class, like you tried to do.   I'm not sure of a straightforward way then to replicate the Maven precedence:  parameter XML config, then sysprop, then project prop, then defaultValue like you tried to do.  (And I imagine it'd be hard to find documentation on this).

Comment: (Continuing .....) Obviously if you can find an example doing something like this, or maybe ask the Maven users list, that might help.  Another idea:  you could simply implement the setter method on your Mojo to read a sysprop.  This isn't equivalent to your initial idea, and you'd have to do it with every Mojo, not just once for the Settings bean. It'd be more work to incorporate project props too (in the pom).  OTOH, you could implement it however you want.  Many people are surprised that the -Dx=y on CLI does NOT have precedence over XML plugin config.. you could have your own custom logic.

Comment: (If this sounds interesting I could post an answer as an example)